# redis stop-start problem (6.2.13 version)

Tags: redis, rhel, redis-sentinel

I'm running redis sentinel on rhel machines. However, when I try to stop the redis-sentinel service with the systemctl stop command, the service either stops after a very long time or cannot be stopped. When I try to start again, it doesn't start. When I looked with the ps aux command, I saw that the process when the first service was started was not killed. Since the process is not killed, the port does not become vacant and it cannot start because it will use the same port when starting. How do I solve this problem? My machine is Rhel8 and my redis version is 6.2.13.

I rebooted the machine and saw that the problem was solved. But it repeats every time I stop. I tried to kill the process but it failed.